# Vue Resource - Post multiple data

Tags: vue.js, vue-resource

I have the following:

```
bidAmount: {
    amount: 0
},
userToken: {
    token: null
},

this.$http.post('/place-bet', this.bidAmount, function(response) {
    alert(response);
});
```

How do I send both `this.bidAmount` and `this.userToken`

I have tried this however it doesn't send correctly:

```
this.$http.post('/place-bet', [this.userToken, this.bidAmount], function(response) {
    alert(response);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should always post an object, that way you can access the variables on the server using their respective keys:

```
this.$http.post('/place-bet', {userToken: this.userToken, bidAmount: this.bidAmount}, function(response) {
    alert(response);
});
```

or...

```
this.$http.post('/place-bet', {data:[this.userToken, this.bidAmount]}, function(response) {
    alert(response);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an object in data object

```
new vue({
 el:'#point'
data: {

newdata:{
token:'',
bidAmount:''
 }
}

});
```

Now you can

```
this.$http.post('/place-bet',this.newdata, function(response) {
    alert(response);
});
```